# how do I safely write data from a single hdf5 file to multiple files in parallel in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, h5py

I am trying to write my data (from a single file in hdf5 format) to multiple files, and it works fine when the task is executed in serial. Now I want to improve the efficiency and modify the code using the `multiprocessing` module, but the output sometimes go wrong. Here's a simplified version of my code.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import math, h5py, time
N = 4  # number of processes to use
block_size = 300
data_sz = 678
dataFile = 'mydata.h5'

# fake some data
mydata = np.zeros((data_sz, 1))
for i in range(data_sz):
    mydata[i, 0] = i+1
h5file = h5py.File(dataFile, 'w')
h5file.create_dataset('train', data=mydata)

# fire multiple workers
pool = mp.Pool(processes=N)
total_part = int(math.ceil(1. * data_sz / block_size))
for i in range(total_part):
    pool.apply_async(data_write_func, args=(dataFile, i, ))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

and the `data_write_func()`'s structure is:

```
def data_write_func(h5file_dir, i, block_size=block_size):
    hf = h5py.File(h5file_dir)
    fout = open('data_part_' + str(i), 'w')
    data_part = hf['train'][block_size*i : min(block_size*(i+1), data_sz)]  # np.ndarray
    for line in data_part:
        # do some processing, that takes a while...
        time.sleep(0.01)
        # then write out..
        fout.write(str(line[0]) + '\n')
    fout.close()
```

when I set `N=1`, it works well. but when I set `N=2` or `N=4`, the result get messed sometimes(not every time!). e.g. in data_part_1 I expect the output to be:

```
301,
302,
303,
...
```

But sometimes what I get is

```
0,
0,
0,
...
```

sometimes I get

```
379,
380,
381,
...
```

I'm new to the multiprocessing module, and find it tricky. Appreciate it if any suggestions!

Comment: Please clarify better your question: what do you mean with "the results order seems messed"? What is the expected behaviour and what is the actual outcome?

Comment: can you post a source code which works? E.g. Andriy's source code below works but he needed to correct the `mydata` and the `fout.write` part

Answer (score 6):

After fixing the `fout.write` and `mydata=...` as Andriy suggested your program works as intended, because every process writes to his own file. There's no way the processes intermingle with each other.

What you *probaby* wanted to do is using `multiprocessing.map()` which cuts your iterable for you (so you don't need to do the `block_size` thingies), plus it guarantees that the results are done in order. I've reworked your code to use multiprocessing map:

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial
import pprint

def data_write_func(line):
  i = multiprocessing.current_process()._identity[0]
  line = [i*2 for i in line]
  files[i-1].write(",".join((str(s) for s in line)) + "\n")

N = 4
mydata=[[x+1,x+2,x+3,x+4] for x in range(0,4000*N,4)] # fake some data
files = [open('data_part_'+str(i), 'w') for i in range(N)]

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=N)
pool.map(data_write_func, mydata)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Please note:

- i is taken from the process itself, it's either 1 or 2
- as now `data_write_func` is called for every row, the file opening needs to be done in the parent process. Also: you don't need to do the `close()` the file manually, the OS will do that for you on exit of your python program.

Now, I guess in the end you'd want to have all the output in **one** file, not in separate files. If your output line is below 4096 bytes on linux (or below 512 bytes on OSX, for other OSes see [here](http://ar.to/notes/posix#pipe-buf)) you're actually safe to just open one file (in append mode) and let every process just write into that one file, as writes below these sizes are guaranteed to be atomic by Unix.

**Update**:

> "What if the data is stored in hdf5 file as dataset?"

According to [hdf5 doc this works out of the box since version 2.2.0](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/mpi.html):

> Parallel HDF5 is a configuration of the HDF5 library which lets you share open files across multiple parallel processes. It uses the MPI (Message Passing Interface) standard for interprocess communication

So if you do this in your code:

```
h5file = h5py.File(dataFile, 'w')
dset = h5file.create_dataset('train', data=mydata)
```

Then you can just access dset from within your process and read/write to it without taking any extra measures. See also [this example from h5py using multiprocessing](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/master/examples/multiprocessing_example.py)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! `map` is good, but I want to be able to specify number of processes, which equals number of output files, rather than for each row. And sorry for not clarifying it in yesterday's post. I've updated my question now. Could you help to find out the bug?

Comment: @JenkinsY just take the code above and replace `N = 4` by the number of processes you need and you'll get this number of processes each writing to his own file. So for N=8 you'll get 8 processes and 8 files `data_part_0` .. `data_part_7`

Comment: @ hansaplast What if the data is stored in hdf5 file as dataset, rather than a python list in memory?

Comment: @JenkinsY, this works "out of the box". I answered your question now in a new section of my answer

Comment: Thanks! the link you provided says **Trying to interact with the same file on disk from multiple processes results in undefined behavior.**  So that may be the reason for the bug I encountered.

Comment: @JenkinsY: oh, good catch! can you try it with the mpio driver as [explained in here](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/mpi.html#using-parallel-hdf5-from-h5py)?

Answer (score 2):

The issue could not be replicated. Here is my full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import multiprocessing

N = 4
mydata=[[x+1,x+2,x+3,x+4] for x in range(0,4000*N,4)] # fake some data

def data_write_func(mydata, i, block_size=1000):
    fout = open('data_part_'+str(i), 'w')
    data_part = mydata[block_size*i: block_size*i+block_size]
    for line in data_part:
        # do some processing, say *2 for each element...
        line = [x*2 for x in line]
        # then write out..
        fout.write(','.join(map(str,line))+'\n')
    fout.close()

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=N)
for i in range(2):
      pool.apply_async(data_write_func, (mydata, i, ))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Sample output from `data_part_0`:

```
2,4,6,8
10,12,14,16
18,20,22,24
26,28,30,32
34,36,38,40
42,44,46,48
50,52,54,56
58,60,62,64
```

Comment: Sorry that my first code simplies too much. I've updated my post now. the issue is so tricky because it can be replicated sometimes, but not all the time.

Answer (score -2):

multiprocessing cannot guarantee the order of code execution between different threads, it is perfectly reasonable for 2 processes to execute in reverse order of their creation order (at least on windows and mainstream linux)

usually when you use parallelization you need worker threads to **generate** the data then aggregate the data into a thread safe data structure and save that to file, but you are writing to one file here, presumably on to one hard disk, do you have any reason to believe you will get any additional performance by using multiple threads?

Comment: multiprocessing.map() is guaranteed to be "in order", also you're mentioning "threads" when multiprocessing works with processes

Comment: processes and threads are weird in python, you can't get true parallelism with normal threads, the only option is to use multiprocessing, so i call them threads: meaning they logically SHOULD share resources and probably DO share resources and multiprocessing definitely can't force the write operations order to the disk... also multiprocessing has no kernel side code so it cannot force the OS to run one thread before the other (yes this time its threads, the cpu doesn't see processes)

Comment: in python there's both multithreading and multiprocessing so you should use the same wording, otherwise it's just confusing